# back stack keeps adding when using Intents

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, fragment-backstack

I have an activity A which uses a fragment A which has a list. The activity A can call on a search activity. The problem that I am seeing is if I were to go the search activity and then go back to the activity A, from there fragment A gets loaded. If I select an item from Fragment A i get taken to Fragment B, if i were to press the back button i have to click it 2 or 3 times. Any ideas? Do i need to start the search activity with a parameter so it does not add to the back stack. I have tried the Flag to Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP when starting the search activity but the issue occurs.

Java:

Activity A:

```
public void popFragment(){
    if(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
    }
}
```

Fragment A:

```
private void showSearchActivity(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, SearchActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0)
}
```

Comment: You will have to share your implementation. Especially the backstack part of the code(how you managing your fragments in the backstack) to determine what is going on.

Comment: @HaroldSer Thank you for getting back to me I updated my code!